# Echoing to a command after a delay in Bash

Tags: bash, command, echo

I want to copy a .bin file in a .img file using mcopy. For this, I can use `mcopy -i image.img bin.bin ::`. When using this, it will tell me: `Long file name "bin.bin" already exists.
a)utorename A)utorename-all r)ename R)ename-all o)verwrite O)verwrite-all
s)kip S)kip-all q)uit (aArRoOsSq):`. Due to the size and importance of stable files in this project, I just always want to put in `O` (small size and no importance, just so you know).

So I searched, and found this could be done by using the command: `echo "O" | mcopy -i image.img bin.bin ::`. Great. However, mcopy has a slight delay, due to which the echo does NOT enter `O` on the right time (too soon). I tried to use `{ sleep 2; echo "O"; } | mcopy -i image.img bin.bin ::`, which helps nothing either.

So: How to actually `echo` text to a command after a delay, using `bash`?

(For the comments: adding -n to the `mcopy` command does neither work)

EDIT: There seemed to be some confusion about the purpose of the question, so I will try to clarify it. Point is, I have a problem and I want it solved. This could be done by using `mcopy` in an alternative way, as proposed in the comments already, OR by delaying the `echo` to the command (as is the question).
Even if my problem is solved in a way where the `mcopy` command is altered, that still would not answer the question. So please keep that in mind.

Comment: why not use mcopy -f if you are happy to overwrite each time?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). The real question is to make `mcopy` overwrite a target automatically.

Comment: @suspectus: The `-f` option seems not to exist :O
@Chepner: Well, it could be. I am also very interested in how to delay my automatic echo input to a command ;)

Comment: delete original file before copying. Otherwise consider `expect` script.

Comment: Ah. `mcopy -D o -i image.img bin.bin ::` solved my problem. Not an answer to the question, though, explicitely said. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question, and you already know the answer to the question you're asking.

For the question "How to actually echo text to a command after a delay, using bash?", the answer is precisely:

```
 { sleep $DELAY; echo $TEXT; } | command
```

However, that should hardly ever be necessary. It provides the given text to `command`'s standard input after the given delay, which may cause the command to wait a bit before proceeding with the read input. But there is (almost) never a case where the data needs to be delayed until the command is already waiting for it -- *if the command is reading from standard input*.

In the case of `mtools`, however, `mcopy` is *not* reading the clash code from standard input. Instead, it is reading it directly from `/dev/tty`, which is the terminal associated with the command. Redirecting standard input, which is what the bash pipe operator does, has no effect on `/dev/tty`. Consequently, the problem is not that you need to delay sending data to `mcopy`'s standard input; the problem is that mcopy doesn't use standard input, and bash has no mechanism to hijack `/dev/tty` in order to fake user input.

So the other question might be "how to programmatically tell `mcopy` which clash option to use?", but apparently you know the answer to that one, too: use the `-D` command line option (which works with all relevant `mtools` utilities).

Finally, a more complicated question: "Is there some way to automate a utility which insists on reading input from `/dev/tty`?" Here, the answer is "yes" but the techniques are not so simple as just piping. The most common way is to use the `expect` utility, which allows you to spawn a subprocess whose `/dev/tty` is a pseudo-tty which `expect` can communicate with.